# Heroku advertisement banner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ads

This morning when I opened my heroku app in the browser, I noticed a banner advertisement was placed on the bottom. I added an instance (as to not be a free plan) and restarted my server, and it was still there.

I dug through their knowledgebase and stackoverflow, can't figure out how to remove these. Right now I am removing them with JS, but the goal is to not receive the extra load / advertisements.

Comment: I'm not aware of any advertisement injected in customer pages. A screenshot or the URL of the site would help to debug.

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of most of these sites, you can see the ad banner. Raises another question why they're not all receiving the ad.
https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:herokuapp.com&oq=site:herokuapp.com

My app is at http://paddlar.herokuapp.com/rivers, though I'm using JS to remove the changes for now.

Comment: That sounds like you have something between you and the server injecting JS into the page. Are you using a free WiFi hotspot? I've heard of some airports in Europe starting to inject JS ads at their proxy, between the user and the open web. Most likely, though, you've got something malicious running in your browser.

Comment: One more thing - there's no need to restart anything when you scale. The changes take effect immediately. More precisely, each instance (dyno) is a virtualized server unto itself.

Comment: None of those sites is showing an ads to me.

Comment: No ads for me either. It would really surprise me if these were from Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku will not inject adds into your site whether it's free or not. As mentioned in comments to your question, you should check whether it's something that's done by the network you're on. Maybe try accessing your site using https (i.e. https://paddlar.herokuapp.com/rivers) - with that, the network should not be able to modify responses.

Comment: Crap. I viewed the app with my iPhone to confirm it wasn't my router, and there were no ads. I removed all Chrome extensions and wiped my Chromebook, and the ads are gone. Looks like I had a malicious extension. 

Thank you!