# Why is my site on heroku loading ad scripts?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, heroku

There are site sources on localhost

[image: site sources on localhost]

And there are site sources on heroku

[image: site sources on heroku]

And we can see that there are many unnecessary scripts on heroku.

I use this buildpack: [jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack](https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack). I looked into its sources and found nothing suspicious. And in the issues, no one had such a problem.

I tried to start in safe mode (no addons) but the problem persists :(

Comment: maybe its because its free and this is part of the service that provides for free ?

Comment: Ini this question the problem lies with the user, not Heroku it would seem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902600/heroku-advertisement-banner

Comment: How are you viewing that "site sources on Heroku" list?

Comment: @Aristos A person has already asked and he was told that heroku does not embed ads
@VDWWD I've seen this question, but what's the problem then?
@Chris i`m pressing i`m pressing F12 and go to the sources tab

Comment: @olegshmel, so that's from your browser? Do you see the same thing in an incognito window / with all extensions disabled?

Comment: @Chris I wrote in question I tried to run with all extensions disabled. In an incognito the same thing